Is in TorchSharp implementation of TorchText completed? If not, what are alternatives?
For TorchSharp text classification example there is TorchText used to load data set.
I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but I can not find any usings to import this library.
For TorchSharp MNIST example I did manage to find and install proper NuGet to use torchvision.
Is TorchText implemented for .NET?
If not, alternatively, how can I load data from CSV file? I do not know what data type should be used for var reader in the example? Im confused.

It is not a library, but part of Examples project AG_NEWSReader
